# Program copying files incorrectly

Tags: c, file, copy

So for an assignment in my Systems class, we have to make a program that takes a file in a given source and copies it to a given destination using one of three copyfile() functions.

When running the program in the command line, it will take in three arguments: ./cptest, the input file location, and the output file location, as well as two optional arguments: the number for which copyfile() function you would like to use as well as the buffer size.

If you choose 1 for the copyfile() function parameter, the program should copy the file using formatted I/O (file handles), and then copy the file one character at a time.

If you choose 2 for the copyfile() function parameter, the program should copy the file using integer file descriptors, and then copy the file one character at a time.

If you choose 3 for the copyfile() function parameter, the program should allocate a buffer of size equal to what size you put in for the buffer size parameter (say 1024), then use read() to read from the input file up to that many bytes at a time.

If you do not put in a third parameter (copyfile() function number), then the program will automatically use copyfile3() with whatever buffer size you decided with the fourth parameter.

If you do not enter a fourth parameter (buffer size), then the program will set it to 1024 by default and use it if necessary (not needed for copyfile1() or 2()).

Before and after each copyfile() function is called, the program uses gettimeofday() to make a timestamp. The program then makes a new timestamp to find how long the copying took using the difference in seconds and microseconds between the after timestamp and the before timestamp, then prints all this information out.

For example if I put in: ./cptest ~/My_Documents/photo.JPG ~/assig6/photo.JPG 3 
The program should return:

Timestamp Before Copying:
 Seconds: 1425150842, Microseconds: 914511
Timestamp After Copying:
 Seconds: 1425150842, Microseconds: 927662
Copying took 0 seconds, 13151 microseconds

So now that you know what the program does, let's get down to the issue. Every time I run the programs with any of the copyfile() functions, be it 1, 2, or 3, technically speaking, the copying works fine, the file ends up in the correct destination, and the program returns all the correct information in terms of the timestamps.

However, in reality, it does not work, as when I use copyfile1(), it copies all of the bytes, but when I try to open the file - say a .jpg - it says that it can't view the file because it appears to be damaged, corrupted, or too large. When I use copyfile2() and copyfile3(), the file in the destination has only 1 KB, and when I don't pass in a third or fourth parameter, the output file has 0 KB. The same thing happens with word documents.

Is there a reason why it copies the files fine but the file is damaged in the process? It seems as though the code is right but the end result is not.

Here's the main file cptest.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "cptest.h"

/** cptest.cpp
 * A file copying program.
 * Derived partially from caesar.cpp by Horstmann and Budd from big C++
 */

/** Prints usage instructions.
 * @param program_name the name of this program
 */
void usage(char* program_name) {  
  // Prints out usage instructions if incorrect number of parameters is passed in
  printf("Usage: %s infile outfile copy_function_number buffer_size \n", program_name);
}

/** Prints file opening error message
 * @param filename the name of the file that could not be opened
 */
void open_file_error(char* filename) {  
  // Error message if unable to open the file
  printf("Error opening file %s\n", filename);
}

/** Main program: copies a file.
 * @param argc Number of command-line arguments (including program name).
 * @param argv Array of pointers to character arays holding arguments.
 * @return 0 if successful, 1 if failure.
 */
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {  
  char* infilename; // Name of input file
  char* outfilename; // Name of output file
  int copy_function_number; // Chooses which copy function is used based on argv[3]
  int buffer_size; // Size of buffer
  int returnstatus; // 0 or 1 depending on success or failure to copy the file to the destination
  struct timeval* before = malloc(sizeof(struct timeval)); // Struct for time before copying is done
  struct timeval* after = malloc(sizeof(struct timeval)); // Struct for time after copying is done

  if (argc != 3 && argc != 4 && argc != 5) {
    usage(argv[0]); // Must have 2, 3, or 4 arguments in addition to ./cptest.
    return 1; // Failure!
  }

  infilename = argv[1]; // Sets first parameter to the input file name
  outfilename = argv[2]; // Sets second parameter to the output file name

  if(argv[3] == NULL) {
    copy_function_number = 3; // Program uses copyfile3 if no third parameter is entered
  }

  else {
    copy_function_number = atoi(argv[3]); // Otherwise program uses whatever function is passed by third parameter
  }

  if (argv[4] == NULL) {
    buffer_size = 1024; // Sets buffer size to 1024 if no fourth parameter is entered
  }

  else {
    buffer_size = atoi(argv[4]); // Otherwise buffer size is whatever user enters as fourth parameter
  }

  if (copy_function_number == 1) {
    gettimeofday(before, NULL); // Get timestamp before the copying
    // Perform the copying with copyfile1() if the third parameter is 1
    returnstatus = copyfile1(infilename, outfilename); 
    gettimeofday(after, NULL); // Get timestamp after the copying
  }

  if (copy_function_number == 2) {
    gettimeofday(before, NULL); // Get timestamp before the copying
    // Perform the copying with copyfile2() if the third parameter is 2
    returnstatus = copyfile2(infilename, outfilename);  
    gettimeofday(after, NULL); // Get timestamp after the copying
  }

  if (copy_function_number == 3) {
    gettimeofday(before, NULL); // Get timestamp before the copying
    // Perform the copying with copyfile3() if the third parameter is 3
    returnstatus = copyfile3(infilename, outfilename, buffer_size);  
    gettimeofday(after, NULL); // Get timestamp after the copying
  }

  else {
    if (copy_function_number != 1 || copy_function_number != 2 || copy_function_number != 3 || argv[3] == NULL) {
      gettimeofday(before, NULL); // Get timestamp before the copying
      // Perform the copying with copyfile3() if no third parameter is entered
      returnstatus = copyfile3(infilename, outfilename, buffer_size);  
      gettimeofday(after, NULL); // Get timestamp after the copying
    }
  }

  struct timeval *copytime = difference_in_time(before, after); // Struct for time after copying is done

  // Print out information of the timestamp before copying
  printf("Timestamp Before Copying: \n Seconds: %d, Microseconds: %d\n", before->tv_sec, before->tv_usec);
  // Print out information of the timestamp after copying
  printf("Timestamp After Copying: \n Seconds: %d, Microseconds: %d\n", after->tv_sec, after->tv_usec);
  // Print out information of the difference between the timestamps (how long the copying took)
  printf("Copying took %d seconds, %d microseconds\n", copytime->tv_sec, copytime->tv_usec);

  return returnstatus; // 0 if successful copy, 1 if unsuccessful.
}

/** Copies one file to another using formatted I/O, one character at a time.
 * @param infilename Name of input file
 * @param outfilename Name of output file
 * @return 0 if successful, 1 if error.
 */
int copyfile1(char* infilename, char* outfilename) {
  FILE* infile; //File handle for source.
  FILE* outfile; // File handle for destination.

  infile = fopen(infilename, "r"); // Open the input file.
  if (infile == NULL) {
    open_file_error(infilename); // Error message if there was a problem opening the input file.
    return 1; // Failure!
  }

  outfile = fopen(outfilename, "w"); // Open the output file.
  if (outfile == NULL) {
    open_file_error(outfilename); // Error message if there was a problem opening the output file.
    return 1; // Failure!
  }

  int intch;  // Character read from input file. must be an int to catch EOF.
  unsigned char ch; // Character stripped down to a byte.

  // Read each character from the file, checking for EOF.
  while ((intch = fgetc(infile)) != EOF) {
    ch = (unsigned char) intch; // Convert to one-byte char.
    fputc(ch, outfile); // Write out.
  }

  fclose(infile); // Close the input file.
  fclose(outfile); // Close the output file.

  return 0; // Success!
}

/** Copies one file to another using integer file descriptors instead of file handles, one character at a time.
 * @param infilename Name of input file
 * @param outfilename Name of output file
 * @return 0 if successful, 1 if error.
 */
int copyfile2(char* infilename, char* outfilename) {
  int infile; //File handle for source.
  int outfile; // File handle for destination.
  // Allocates a buffer for the chars that will be read from the input and written to the output.
  char buffer[1024]; 

  infile = open(infilename, O_RDONLY); // Open the input file.
  if (infile < 0) {
    open_file_error(infilename); // Error message if there was a problem opening the input file.
    return 1; // Failure!
  }

  outfile = open(outfilename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT); // Open the output file.
  if (outfile < 0) {
    open_file_error(outfilename); // Error message if there was a problem opening the output file.
    return 1; // Failure!
  } 

  int intchin;  // Character read from input file. must be an int to catch EOF.
  int intchout; // Character written to the output file. must be an int to catch EOF.
  // Size of the buffer so that when you are copying extremely large files, it does not have to go through 200000 loop iterations
  int buffer_size = 1024; 
  unsigned char ch; // Character stripped down to a byte.

  // Read each character from the file, checking for 0.
  while ((intchin = read(infile, buffer, buffer_size)) != 0) {
    ch = (unsigned char) intchin; // Convert to one-byte char.
    intchout = write(outfile, buffer, ch); // Write out.
  }

  close(intchin); // Close the input file.
  close(intchout); // Close the output file.

  return 0; // Success!
}

/** Copies one file to another using integer file descriptors, buffer_size characters at a time.
 * @param infilename Name of input file
 * @param outfilename Name of output file
 * @param buffer_size Size of the buffer for reading and writing
 * @return 0 if successful, 1 if error.
 */
int copyfile3(char* infilename, char* outfilename, int buffer_size) {
  int infile; //File handle for source.
  int outfile; // File handle for destination.
  // Allocates a buffer of size buffer_size for the chars that will be read from the input and written to the output.
  char* buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)* buffer_size); 

  infile = open(infilename, O_RDONLY); // Open the input file.
  if (infile < 0) {
    open_file_error(infilename); // Error message if there was a problem opening the input file.
    return 1; // Failure!
  } 

  outfile = open(outfilename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT); // Open the output file.
  if (outfile < 0) {
    open_file_error(outfilename); // Error message if there was a problem opening the output file.
    return 1; // Failure!
  } 

  int intchin;  // Character read from input file. must be an int to catch EOF.
  int intchout; // Character written to the output file. must be an int to catch EOF.
  unsigned char ch; // Character stripped down to a byte.

  // Read each character from the file, checking for 0.
  while ((intchin = read(infile, buffer, buffer_size)) != 0) {
    ch = (unsigned char) intchin; // Convert to one-byte char.
    intchout = write(outfile, buffer, ch); // Write out.
  }

  close(intchin); // Close the input file.
  close(intchout); // Close the output file.
  free(buffer); // Free the buffer that was allocated.

  return 0; // Success!
}

/** Makes a new timeval struct that determines the difference between two timestamps
 * @param time1 Struct containing the information for the first timestamp
 * @param time2 Struct containing the information for the second timestamp
 * @return The struct made using the two parameters
 */
struct timeval* difference_in_time(struct timeval* time1, struct timeval* time2) {
  struct timeval* copytime = malloc(sizeof(struct timeval)); // Allocates a struct to hold the difference between the two timestamps.

  if ((time2->tv_sec - time1->tv_sec) < 0) {  
    // Error message for if the first timestamp entered was before the second timestamp.
    printf("Seconds value is negative! time1 should be before time2!\n"); 
  }

  if ((time2->tv_usec - time1->tv_usec) < 0) {
    // Handles if the difference in microseconds between the second and first timestamps would be negative, subtracting 1 from the seconds.
    copytime->tv_sec = (time2->tv_sec - time1->tv_sec) - 1; 
    // Handles if the difference in microseconds between the second and first timestamps would be negative, subtracting the difference from 1000000.
    copytime->tv_usec = 1000000 - (time2->tv_usec - time1->tv_usec); 
  }

  else {
    // Otherwise the seconds for the third timestamp is the difference between the seconds of the second and first timestamps.
    copytime->tv_sec = (time2->tv_sec - time1->tv_sec); 
    // Otherwise the microseconds for the third timestamp is the difference between the microseconds of the second and first timestamps.
    copytime->tv_usec = (time2->tv_usec - time1->tv_usec); 
  }

  return copytime; // Return the new timestamp created.
}
```

Here's the header file cptest.h:

```
#ifndef CPTEST_H
#define CPTEST_H

// function prototypes
void usage(char* program_name);
void open_file_error(char* filename);
int copyfile1(char* infilename, char* outfilename);
int copyfile2(char* infilename, char* outfilename);
int copyfile3(char* infilename, char* outfilename, int buffer_size);
struct timeval* difference_in_time(struct timeval* time1, struct timeval* time2);

#endif
```

And here's the makefile:

```
cptest: cptest.o
    gcc -g cptest.o -o cptest

cptest.o: cptest.c cptest.h
    gcc -c -g cptest.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o cptest

docs:
    doxygen
    chmod a+r html/*
    cp -p html/* ~/public_html/cs2303assig6
```

EDIT: Thought it might be easier to show you what happens using the readme.txt we need to include with our program as an example. Shortened it down to the useful information so you don't have to through more walls of text.

Original:

```
Name: *My name*
Section: CS2303 C01

What Program Does: *Explanation of what program does*

Example: *Example of what should show up when running program in the command line*

Results: *Test data for time it took for each function and using different buffer sizes to find most efficient function and buffer size*

Compiling:

To compile the code, use 'make' in the command line. The makefile should already link all of the .o files to the executable, so the work is done for you.
```

Result when using copyfile1():

```
so the work is done for you.S2303 C01

What Program Does: *Explanation of what program does*

Example: *Example of what should show up when running program in the command line*

Results: *Test data for time it took for each function and using different buffer sizes to find most efficient function and buffer size*

Compiling:

To compile the code, use 'make' in the command line. The makefile should already link all of the .o files to the executable, so the work is done for you.
```

Result when using copyfile2() and 3():

```
so the work is done for you.
```

Answer (score 0):

copyfile2 and 3 are completely broken because they cast the number of characters read into a char.  As the buffer size is often 1024, this cast gives a result of 0 so nothing is written.

For copyfile 1, I'd recommend opening the files with a binary flag ("rb" or "wb") although I'm not convinced that is the issue.

Comment: So the odd thing is that our professor gave us copyfile1, and so unless he screwed up, it should copy the file correctly. I just checked, and using rb and wb doesn't change anything. How should I fix 2 and 3 so it doesn't give a result of 0?

Comment: As a start, don't cast the return from read - it is an integer and should be kept as such when passed to write (in truth, it should be size_t but for now int will do).

Comment: When I take out the ch = (unsigned char) intchin and just make intchout = write(outfile, buffer, intchin), when I run it it never really finishes executing it (that or it's taking a really long time to copy and I just don't have the patience for it :P).

Comment: Never mind. Fixed a few dumb errors that I did when taking out the ch part, so now copyfile1 and 3 seem to work fine, and copyfile2 works with jpgs, but adds my information about the timestamps to the end of my readme when I use that as the file.

Comment: Fixed an error in closing the files so now all the functions work properly :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah - I missed that entirely :)